# Coverage unittest fails in Python 3.8

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, test-coverage

I am struggling with the implementation of unittest for subdirectories. I have the following project

```
project
│   README.md
│   __init__.py
│
└───common    
│   __init__.py
│   └───my_func
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   func1.py
│       │   func2.py
│
└───scripts
│   __init__.py
│   └───folder_1
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   code1.py
│   │   code2.py
│   
│   └───folder_2
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   code3.py
│   │   code4.py
│   │
│   └───tests
│   │   └───test1
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   test_code3.py
│   │   │   test_code4.py
│   │   │      
│   │   └───test2
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │   test_code3.py
│   │   │   test_code4.py
```

I set the working directory to be ./project. In my *code1.py* file I import *common.my_func.func1* and it runs normally.

Now, I am trying to implement some unittest functions in `./project/scripts/tests`. To do so, I am using the coverage package and running the command: `coverage run --source=scripts -m unittest discover scripts/tests`. However, when  doing so, I get the following error:

`ModeluNotFoundError: No module named common.my_func`

Weirdly speaking, the scripts works perfectly when I try to run it for one test folder only, and not the whole folder `coverage run --source=scripts -m unittest discover scripts/tests/test1`.

I tried multiple combinations of removing the source, getting more specific with the folder and on. Have any of you faced similar problems with python 3.8?

Thank you very much in advance,

Comment: Have you tried setting the source as `project`? Something like this: `coverage run --source=project -m unittest discover project/scripts/tests`. The reason I ask is because when you're in the scope of `scripts` directory, how does the coverage command know to look outside that scope?

Comment: I have yeah. But still same issue :/
I think it should now because I am running my command lines on ./lucas/project>